# Calculating charging current

Tags: current, charging

I have following situation:

Solarpanel with 20 W, 2 12V lead-acid batteries, the solar panel is charing the batteries. I measure the current coming from the panel with a ACS712 in a 3 minute interval.

The output then looks as following:

```
Amp;Date
1.08699;"2015-05-07 12:42:33"
1.09222;"2015-05-07 12:45:33"
1.00338;"2015-05-07 12:48:32"
0.984217;"2015-05-07 12:51:32"
1.06783;"2015-05-07 12:54:33"
1.01557;"2015-05-07 12:57:33"
0.386719;"2015-05-07 13:00:32"
```

I want to calculate the total ampere hours of a day.
I had the followin in mind:

As the ACS712 is very noisy, I set all values below 0.10 amps to 0.
I square every value, then sum it, then divide by the amount of values I have for each day.
Then I multiply by the amount of seconds that have passed between start and end.

The result is the charging current for that day, I think. Is this a viable approach to this problem, or should I skip the squaring part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the squaring. You are trying to integrate current, not power. And don't bother limiting the low values, either. Just sum them up, multiply by time between samples, and divide by total time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you sure to skip the low values? I have values that can't be true (like +-0,06 amps in the middle of the night)

Comment: Shrug. Up to you. Do you get negative values as well? Take a look at the total reading for a night, and see if the noise averages out.

Comment: Yes, negative values too.

Comment: So give it at try. Since you're not going to be squaring the values, false negatives will probably cancel out false positives. Certainly taking data when you KNOW there's no light will allow you to get an idea of the ACS712's response to zero input.

Comment: You are right, I averaged 6 hours of darkness and the result is -0,009 amps, which I think can be ignored.

Comment: You'll note that, for the data you showed, you can assume the zero error is about 1% of the total, which is more than adequate for a working system.

Comment: True. One last question: I sum up the values from one day, if I multiply them by 180 and divide by 86400 I get values that don't seem logical to me. If I however multiply them by 180 and then use that value to convert to Ah the values seem logical to me. (e.g sum from today is 90, which equals in ~4,5 Ah)

Comment: You're right, I was wrong. Don't multiply by total time. Watch the units. Let's say you're getting a constant 1 amp at 3 minute intervals over 12 hours. That's 240 samples of 1 amp each. 240 x 1/20 = 12 amp-hrs, and the time interval (3 minutes) is expressed as 1/20 hours.